Were Cimmerian, Scythian, and Sarmatian Satem-languages?
Were Cimmerian, Scythian, and Sarmatian Satem-languages? I know that these languages are almost unattested. But maybe there is a word or name which gives a clue. I'm asking this because of the report of Herodotus on the scythian sauna and the scythian word for hemp being cannabis. This is strange because the other indo-iranian languages all have sana or something similar (afaik). Even Ossetian has san (nowadays the word for wine, isn't it). And Ossetian is a descendant of these 'steppe-iranian' languages. This is why I wonder whether Herodotus can be trusted or not.

Slavic *sъ̏to might be Iranian borrowing. Compare Lithuanian šim̃tas, Avestan sata, Sanskrit śatá.

The Ossetian reflex of κάνναβις is гӕн (gæn), isn't it? Persian also has kanaf, and AFAIK none of the Slavic reflexes show satemisation in the word, so Ossetian сæн must be something else.

The Scythian sauna? Did you mean fauna?

@Janus Bahs Jacquet: Herodotus, The Histories, 4.75: "The Scythians, as I said, take some of this hemp-seed, and, creeping under the felt coverings, throw it upon the red-hot stones; immediately it smokes, and gives out such a vapour as no Grecian vapour-bath can exceed; the Scyths, delighted, shout for joy."

I see – I wasn’t familiar with that, very interesting!

@Cairnarvon: Unfortunately I do not speak Ossetian myself and did not find much ossetian vocabulary online. From the words suggested on glosbe.com/en/os/hemp, гӕн, which means linen, seems to come closest to kana(pis). But I found a note on ossetian san in a german dictionary of Latin: Walde, "Lateinisches Etymologsches Wörterbuch", p. 122-123, lemma: cannabis. There the author mentions "osset. san 'Wein'". The latter seems more reliable to me. If only there was an expert on ossetian etymology who would tell us what's right...

The first thing to note is that Cimmerian, Scythian, and Sarmatian are known (almost) exclusively from texts written in other languages, meaning our knowledge of those languages is inherently somewhat uncertain.
Our knowledge of Cimmerian is exclusively limited to a very small number of personal names which are inherently of limited usefulness. There are proposed Iranic etymologies for these names, but each name has multiple proposed etymologies making them pretty weak evidence.
Scytho-Sarmatian is slightly clearer though, and there is evidence for a satem and specifically Iranic identity. Trying to avoid arguments based solely on the possibility of etymologising these terms as Iranic, and instead on specific features seemingly identifying them as such (and taking as given that they are Indo-European) we have the following pieces of evidence (amongst others):

Αριαπειθης: a personal name, showing the element Arya- (cf Indo-Iranian Arya "Aryan, Iranian"). Potentially compatible with the Germanic personal name element aria- "noble" (likely borrowed from Celtic ario- "noble", which may or may not be cognate with Indo-Iranian Arya).
Σκυθαι and later Σκωλοτοι: both meaning "Scythian" appears to show the /δ/ > /l/ shift seen also in Ossetian.
Παραλαται: a tribal name which, with the above shift in mind is a perfect parallel for Avestan Paraδāta "placed at the front".
Οκταμασαδης & Θαγιμασαδας: a personal and divine name, showing an element mazata-, with a satem reflex of *méǵh₂-o- "great" (as well as consistent a-vocalism found only in Indo-Iranian).
 Bartatua, Προτοθυης, Τιργαταω, & Ταργιταος: personal names and one divine name, seemingly all showing a suffix -tava- cf Avestan -tauuah- "power".
Βορυσθενης: River name, appears to show the -stāna suffix common in Iranic (and only spread much more widely only centuries after this period).
Απι: a goddess associated with water and earth. Appears to show a reflex of *h₂ep- "water". Most branches only attest to a form with Hoffmann's *-h₃on- suffix. Compatible with Tocharian and maybe Italic alongside Indo-Iranian, or could be an otherwise unattested retention in some other branch.

Whilst many of these features are compatible with other identities, an Iranian (and therefore satem) identity is the simplest explanation of the evidence (and secondarily provides us the ability to etymologise a great many names not discussed here).
